# How do you convert a string representing a finite set of strings into a regulair expression without using lots of vertical bars?

Tags: regular-expressions, compilers, parsers

Consider the following string:

```python
stryng = "{\"Jordi\", \"Jordy\", \"Jorde\", \"Jordie\", \"Jordee\", \"Joardi\", \"Joardy\", \"Joarde\", \"Joardie\", \"Joardee\"}"
```

That string represents a mathematical set of strings.

$\begin{Bmatrix} \mathtt{Jordi}, \mathtt{Jordy}, \mathtt{Jorde}, \mathtt{Jordie}, \mathtt{Jordee}, \mathtt{Joardi}, \mathtt{Joardy}, \mathtt{Joarde}, \mathtt{Joardie}, \mathtt{Joardee}\end{Bmatrix}$

If you have a string representation for a set of strings, such as `{"i", "y", "ee"}`, how do you convert that set of strings into a regular expression without the logical-disjunction vertical bar `|`?

I was hoping to have something like a character class except that instead of characters we used strings such that some of the strings were longer than one letter each.

For example, something close to a regular expression might be:

```
Joa?r{"i", "y", "ee"}
```

That fake regex was intended to represent the set of all strings **σ** such that...

> 1. The leftmost part of **σ** is `J`
> 2. The part of **σ** second from the left is `o`
> 3. The part of **σ** third from the left is zero or one instance of the letter `a`
> 4. The fourth part of **σ** is the letter `r`
> 5. The fifth part of **σ** is exactly one of the strings `i`, or `y`, or `ee`.

There is a regular expression `[iye]e?` which is somewhat like the following set:

> `{"i", "y", "e", "ie", "ye", "ee"}`

We want to forbid the string `ye`.

In a python-flavored regex used in the library named `re`, can we write a set of strings, or do we have to write something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "a regular expression without the logical-disjunction vertical bar `|`"?  `|` is part of the syntax of regular expressions.  It's not clear what *is* allowed.  If we take the standard syntax for regexps and remove `|`, all that is left is grouping (`(...)`) and Kleene star (`*`), which doesn't seem very expressive, but there are multiple different definitions of regexp syntax.  Can you provide a self-contained definition of what you *are* looking for, and what definition of regular expression you are using and what syntax *is* allowed?

Comment: I wonder if it might be helpful to provide the motivation for not allowing use of `|`, and for using a regexp for this.  I wonder if this might be a XY problem, but it's hard to know.

Comment: If `Jordye` was in the set too, then `Joa+rd[iye]e+` would work, where `[iye]` means "one character which can be `i, y` or `e`", and `a+` means "zero or one `a`". But without `Jordye` in the set I'm afraid you have to content with `Joa+rd(i|y|e|ie|ee)` or `Joa+rd([iye]|[ie]e)`.

Comment: @D.W. You said it might be helpful to provide the motivation for not allowing use of `|`, and for using a regexp for this. The reason is that in general, I want to convert sets containing thousands of strings into regular expressions so that the regular expressions are short in length. How do we find a reasonably short regex $r$ such that $\forall \sigma \in A$, $\sigma$ and regex $r$ match. Additionally, $\forall \sigma^{\prime} \in A^{-1}$, $\sigma^{\prime}$ and regex $r$ do not match. Note that $A$ is a set of strings and $\sigma$ is a string in set $A$.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon Importantly, note that "regular expression" typically has two distinct meanings. The theoretical meaning, where they are restricted to expressing regular languages; and the meaning from the programming world, whose regexps are like theoretical regexps but with many added superpowers. Here on this site, in the absence of more context, people are going to assume you mean regexps in the sense used in theory, not in the superpowered sense used in programming languages.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon Anyway, there exist different libraries / algorithms designed specifically to build regexps from a list of strings. See for instance [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432830/generating-the-shortest-regex-to-match-an-arbitrary-word-list) or [this github repository](https://github.com/gleenn/regex_compressor)

Answer (score 1):

If `Jordye` was in the set too, then `Joa+rd[iye]e+` would work, where:

- `[iye]` means "one character which can be `i, y` or `e`";
- `a+` means "zero or one `a`".

But without `Jordye` in the set I'm afraid you have to content with either

```
Joa+rd(i|y|e|ie|ee)
```

or

```
Joa+rd([iye]|[ie]e)
```

or

```
Joar+rd(y|[ie]e+)
```

The last one translated directly to a deterministic automaton:

```
                           >O
                        y /  
      J    o    r    d   /
--->o--->o--->o--->o--->o--->O
             /^          ie /^
             \/a            \/e
```